# Move Exchange mailbox 2007 to another Exchange server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We have a couple of hundred users that we are moving to a new domain.
The user accounts will be freshly created on the new domain, but we need to move the mailboxes to a new Exchange server.

We found [this](http://www.exchangedictionary.com/index.php/Exchange-Dictionary/connectmailbox-linkedmailbox-ex2007.html) but this isn't quite what we are after. This will not move the mailbox to a new server..

**Any tips on moving mailboxes to a new exchange server (preferably with Powershell)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up cross-forest mailbox moves. You can do this natively with Exchange 2007/2010. Here's a good starter:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/08/10/3410619.aspx